# How can I save the value of an ID from IE to a variable in VBScript?

Tags: email, variables, internet-explorer, vbscript, internet-explorer-11

I would like to write a program that outputs the email from the website "https://10minutemail.net/" in a message box. Unfortunately, I can't find any code that allows me to store the ID in a variable.

I have tried this already without any results:

```
Dim email
email = ""
set webbrowser = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
webbrowser.statusbar = false
webbrowser.menubar = false
webbrowser.toolbar = false
webbrowser.visible = false
webbrowser.navigate("10minutemail.net") 
email = webbrowser.document.all.item("fe_text")

wscript.echo(email)
```

The code runs with the Error: [unknown error][1].
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1yHF.png

How to fix that?

Comment: Didn’t you ask something similar a few days ago and it was closed?

Comment: Yeah i faild the question... i was new and didnt read how 2 ask a question :/ so i "restarted" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vbscript use HTML DOM with this method `getElementById` to get the particular element in a HTML code source page

So in your case,  you can give a try with this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim IE,Email_Value
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "https://10minutemail.net/"
Do While (IE.Busy)
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop 

Email_Value = IE.document.getElementByID("fe_text").Value
wscript.echo(Email_Value)
IE.Quit()
```

Comment: VBScript doesn’t the HTML DOM on the other hand does.